# Math.Round methodology, starting at the smallest decimal

Tags: c#, math, rounding

There have been many threads started over the confusion in the way that `Math.Round` works. For the most part, those are answered by cluing people in to the `MidpointRounding` parameter and that most people are expecting `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`. I have a further question though about the actual algorithm implemented by AwayFromZero.

Given the following number (the result of a number of calculations): `13.398749999999999999999999999M`

our users are expecting to see the same result that Excel would give them `13.39875`. As they are currently rounding that number to 4 using Math.Round(num, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), the result is off by .0001 from what they expect. Presumably, the reason for this is that the algorithm just looks at the fifth digit (4), and then rounds accordingly. If you were to start rounding at the last 9, the real mathematical answer would in fact give you the same number as excel.

So the question is ... is there a way to emulate this behavior rather than the current?

I've written a recursive function that we *could* use in the meantime. But before we put it in production I wanted to see what SO thought about the problem :-)

```
    private decimal Round(decimal num, int precision)
    {
        return Round(num, precision, 28);
    }

    private decimal Round(decimal num, int precision, int fullPrecision)
    {
        if (precision >= fullPrecision) return Math.Round(num, precision);

        return Round(Math.Round(num, fullPrecision), precision, --fullPrecision);
    }
```

*Edit: just for clarity, I should have been clearer in my original post. The position of rounding methodology being asked for here is what I'm being presented by the business analysts and users who are reporting the "rounding error". Despite being told numerous times that it's not incorrect, just different than what they are expecting ... this report keeps coming in. So I am just on a data gathering stint to gather as much information as I can on this topic to report back to the users.*

*In this case, it seems that any other system used to generate these average prices (which we must match) are using a different level precision (10 in the database, and excel seems to default to 15 or something). Given that everyone has a different level of precision, I'm stuck in the middle with the question of moving to a lower precision, some weird rounding rules (as described above), or just having different results than the users expect.*

Comment: I disagree with the statement "the real mathematical answer would in fact give you the same number as Excel." Mathematical rounding is specifically defined, and it does *not* start from the least-significant digit. Rounding 13.39874999 to 6 significant digits does in fact result in 13.3987, mathematically.

Comment: @Stephen, if I read him correctly, he means he wants to do real math that results in the same result as the flawed approach so as to be bug-compatible.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed. I just wanted to correct the impression that the double-rounding is mathematically correct and therefore expected behavior.

Comment: @Stephen, true. It's hard enough explaining that choices other than elementary-school rounding (that provided by AwayFromZero) aren't wrong, without blurring it further. I think the querant gets this, but we should always think of the person coming in on a google search too.

Comment: These comments are definitely duly noted :-) I added a bit more background as an edit to the post above. Would be great to get some additional thoughts in light of the new information, if it changes your answers any.

Comment: @Joel Martinez: I'm not sure what you are asking. Your Excel example is to 5 places, so why would your users expect the same answer to 4 places?

Comment: @Rick Regan, that's the unrounded result ... they are using that as the basis for their bug report.

Comment: @Joel Martinez: But it's not unrounded -- it's rounded by Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, people are expecting 13.3988 because they are first rounding to 13.39875 and then to 13.3988 and they need you to be bug-compatible with that.

If so, there's no need to repeat any further than one step of rounding, as the flaw in their method only comes in at the last step of rounding (by its nature, rounding removes the significance of the step two steps before it).

```
private static decimal InaccurateRound(decimal num, int precision)
{
  return Math.Round(
    Math.Round(num, precision + 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
    precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Comment: Double rounding is not the final stop. There are corresponding examples for any number of repetitions.
For instance, 0.4444444449 would rounded up to 1 only if you apply rounding AwayFromZero 10 times to each position from right to left.

Answer (score 3):

So if you round that number to 5 places, and then round the result to 4 places... You get a different result than if you just round the original number to 4 places? That's expected. And I think that explains what you need to do. another option is to have Excel show the full precision so "they" round the same way as your code. Rounding twice just seems wrong.